# Using angular directive to watch for change values with bootstrap-select

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angular and after having researched for 2 days, I still haven't come up with a solution that will work yet.

I have a select item that will have its options updated and am also using bootstrap-select.js. I can get either or to work on their own (angular items updating dynamically as expected in a standard select list or the bootstrap-select item to work with static options). If someone could provide some guidance as to what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<selectpicker data-array="users" data-selected="info.selected"></selectpicker>
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope)
{
    $scope.info = {selected: 1};
    $scope.users=[];
    $scope.users.splice(0);
    $scope.users = [{name: "Bob", id: "1"},{name:"Tom", id: "2"}];

     $scope.add = function () {
            $scope.users.push({name: "John", id: "3"});
     };      
}]);

app.directive('selectpicker', function($timeout)
{
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace:true, 
      scope: {
          selected: '=',
          array: '=',
          class: '='
      }, 
  template: '<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count" ng-model="currentName" ng-options="user.name for user in array">' +
      '</select>',
      replace:true,
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          $timeout(function () {
           scope.$watch('array', function (newVal) {

               console.log(scope.array);
               var select = $(el).selectpicker();
              select.change(function(evt) {
                  var val = $(el).selectpicker('val');
                  $scope.selected = val;
                  $scope.$apply();
              });             
          }, true);     
          });
      }           
  };      
});
```

So when I click the Add button, I can see the scope.array value

updates from the console output, but the dropdown itself won't update. I've tried piecing together solutions from similar answers but nothing has yielded results so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation of Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), you could use `refresh()` method to update the UI when an underlying select tag has been changed like this:

```
$(el).selectpicker('refresh');
```

But lets look further how to improve the directive:

1. the element variable `el` is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap it again as `$(el)`.
2. a `$timeout` is become unnecessary after the UI refresh is properly handled.
3. move the change event binding out of `$watch`, otherwise the handler will be fired multiple times per a change.
4. `$watchCollection` is enough if the options will be only add/remove i.e. an individual option will not be changed.

The final result would look like this:

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
  var select = el.selectpicker();
  select.change(function (evt) {
    scope.selected = el.selectpicker('val');
    scope.$apply();
  });

  scope.$watchCollection('array', function(newVal) {
    console.log(scope.array);
    el.selectpicker('refresh');
  });
}
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Kt0V0UBuHaRYMjKbI5Ov?p=preview